# Android BluetoothSocket.connect ask for pairing code every time

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to build a bluetooth connection between a phone and a sensor.
I have two Galaxy S3. My code works fine on one of them, but for the other, my code will always pause at the call `mSocket.connect()`, asking for the pairing code **every time** even if I have already paired the sensor with the phone in the **Settings->Bluetooth**

Please help!
Thanks!
Jake

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. It's because one of my Galaxy phone is in Android 4.04 and the other is in 4.1. Update the Android version will do the trick.